# why appendChild to insert a div inside another div using JavaScript is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following code in JavaScript to insert a div with class = "blah" inside a main div with class = "container" (the main div is created with HTML) but something goes wrong.

```
const board = document.createElement('div');
const mainContainer = document.getElementByClassName('container');
board.className = 'blah';
mainContainer.appendChild(board);
```

The error I get is "Uncaught TypeError: mainContainer.appendChild is not a function". What am I missing?

Thank You for the help

Comment: because `getElementByClassName` method doesn't exist in Javascript. there is only a `getElementsByClassName` method which return a collection of elements, event if this collection have only one element

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that `getElementByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` (note the "s" in Elements). This is because getElementsByClassName returns a collection of all elements in the document that has the specified class name.

```
const board = document.createElement('div');
const mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
board.className = 'blah';
mainContainer.appendChild(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an HTML collection, so you just give `mainContainer` with index do you want.

```js
mainContainer[0].appendChild(board);
```

Full code :

```js
const board = document.createElement('div');
const mainContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
board.className = 'blah';
mainContainer[0].appendChild(board);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error `getElementByClassName` should  be `getElementsByClassName` however assuming that issue is a copy/paste error; your `mainContainer` is not singular even if there is one; it is "an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s)." So you need to iterate over that list to append a child to each one.

example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mainContainer.length; i++) {
    const board = document.createElement('div');
    board.className = 'blah';
    mainContainer[i].appendChild(board);
}
```